# Please allow using nested expressions when filtering with tags

Tags: feature-request, search, tag-search

Please support the use of nested expressions like
[a](/questions/tagged/a) `and` ([b](/questions/tagged/b)`or` [c](/questions/tagged/c))
when searching.

Looking here, on meta, at questions tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) [search](/questions/tagged/search) and at questions found with `+search +tag +boolean` I didn't see any information on this topic.

Comment: This question (request?) is so buried, it took me 15 minutes to find it. And there's no answer! In the Appcelerator Titanium community (which only produces mobile apps), 2671 questions are tagged appcelerator, but a divergence of the open-source Titanium from the commercial Appcelerator offerings means that there are 1336 questions tagged titanium, 626 appcelerator-titanium, 337 appcelerator-mobile and 332 titanium-mobile. So there is effectively no way to find a question on ANY community subject without a majority of questions being excluded because the main subject tag is so fragmented.