# Is there a way to search using more advanced notation?

Tags: feature-request, search, tag-search

First, I want to note that I've read the [Search Help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching).  What I am looking for is a way to group tags together into more advanced boolean statements.  For example, I would like to run the following search:

> ([sql] OR [plsql]) AND [oracle]

This way I get any question tagged with `SQL` or `PLSQL` but only if it also tagged with `ORACLE`.

This is because I'm terrible with `SQL-SERVER`, so I would rather skip it.  I've thought about just adding `-[sql-server]`, but to be honest I don't want to answer questions on any system other than `ORACLE` and adding every other system's tag with the negation operator seems excessive. (But if there isn't a way to do this, that is what I will do).

Comment: related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158815/please-allow-using-nested-expressions-when-filtering-with-tags and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208675/how-do-i-search-using-both-and-and-or

Comment: @rene  Thank you, I really did try searching before posting, but didn't immediately find anything.  Unfortunate that the originals were asked so long ago with no response.  But I upvoted the open one in the hopes that it might some day become reality.